# The role of $\dim H_n$ in the definition of asymptotically continous functions on vectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, mathematical-physics, density-operator

When considering the asymptotic continuity of quantum states, one works with asymptoticallycontinuous functions.

In the definition one has the following, a funtion $f$ is asymptotically cts if for a family of Hilbert spaces $H_n$ with $\dim H_n\rightarrow\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\rho_n = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sigma_n$

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{||f(\rho_n)-f(\sigma_n)||}{\dim H_n}= 0$

where $n$ is in the natural numbers $\rho_n$ and $\sigma_n$ are states in a sequence indexed by $n$, and anything I've missed has the usual definition.

My question is what is the point of $H_n$ with $\dim H_n\rightarrow\infty$ why not simply say when the function on the sequence of states gets arbitarily close so does the difference between the asymptotically cts functions on them? I intend to abstract this definition, and it seems to work fine, however the existence of this dimension term on the bottom for the particular case of vector spaces worries me.

Comment: I guess $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\rho_n=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sigma_n$, as otherwise it would be so trivial as to be useless!

Comment: You're quite right, I've edited to correct it. Any thoughts on the question itself would be most welcome!

Comment: You wrote "one works", which suggests there is a significant body of work using this concept. Any reference? I am afraid I am pretty much an ignorasmus here but I am curious!

Comment: It is a concept of interest in quantum information theory seen through the lens of resource theories (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2162).